# How to remove tag element after successful api hit. Unable to remove them

Tags: reactjs

I have used React-TagEditor with react version 16.6.3 and all its work like a charm, but if I have to clear the added tags after my save all record function I am unable to clear the tags.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a save the array of tags in state and whenever user enter any tag and when your salve all record function executed you can set empty array in state against tags

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am doing that in the same way, i have taken array in state name tags which is populated when we add any tag.  But as after my save function i have made this.setState({tags:[]}) and it empty the tag array but still the tags in tag-Editor is visible.

Comment: then they may be storing that tags in their own store as well, so this is the issue on the package side you can report that issue to them directly from [here](https://github.com/NdYAG/react-tageditor/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc)